# 'cross-env' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, node.js, django, npm, tailwind-css

I'm working on a team in a django project with tailwind following by this set up tutorial https://django-tailwind.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html. everything works find but when i'm starting tailwind
`py manage.py tailwind start`.

```
theme@3.5.0 start
npm run dev      



theme@3.5.0 dev
cross-env NODE_ENV=development tailwindcss --postcss -i ./src/styles.css -o ../static/css/dist/styles.css -w


'cross-env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

here is package.json

```
{
  "name": "theme",
  "version": "3.5.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "build": "npm run build:clean && npm run build:tailwind",
    "build:clean": "rimraf ../static/css/dist",
    "build:tailwind": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production tailwindcss --postcss -i ./src/styles.css -o ../static/css/dist/styles.css --minify",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development tailwindcss --postcss -i ./src/styles.css -o ../static/css/dist/styles.css -w",
    "tailwindcss": "node ./node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/cli.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio": "^0.4.2",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.4.2",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.2",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "postcss-import": "^15.1.0",
    "postcss-nested": "^6.0.0",
    "postcss-simple-vars": "^7.0.1",
    "rimraf": "^4.1.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7"
  }
}
```

do i need to install cross-env? should i install it using npm or pip? in my venv or locally?

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: run the command: `python manage.py tailwind install` to install the dependencies (in which cross-env is included).

I had the same problem as you and what caused the problem is that you possibly did not run the command `python manage.py tailwind install`, which executes the command `npm install` (npm and Node are installed on your machine) which install the dependencies of `devDependencies` (npm installs the dependencies locally in the node_modules folder), this explains the fact that you have the `cross-env` in `devDependencies` and the command was not found.

If that doesn't work, try installing or updating the dependencies using npm without having to use the command I gave you above. Assuming the name of your tailwind app is `'theme'`, go to the `theme/static_src/` folder and run either `npm install` or `npm update` (or use that command to not have to enter in the folder: `python manage.py tailwind update`).

Note: Remember to update Node.